# Starting the default terminal on Linux

Tags: c++, qt

Tell me, please, is it possible to call the `Linux` `Terminal`, which is installed by `default`, in some way (method)?

Now, I run the process in the `xfce4-terminal` terminal, specifying this terminal and the arguments to it:

```
QProcess up;
QString cArg;
 
cArg="/tmp/cp.py -y " + ye;
up.start("xfce4-terminal", QStringList()<< "--geometry=120x40" << "--command" << "python3 "+ cArg << "-H");
up.waitForFinished();
up.close();
```

Comment: No. There is no default, there might not even be a terminal at all and whatever is there may not accept the arguments you're trying to provide. This looks like a so-called "XY problem" (search online for that term), which effectively means you're asking the wrong question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no general way in the Linux kernel to find out which (or whether a) terminal emulator is installed on the system by default.

Although the (fairly ubiquitous) freedesktop.org specifications describe how to associate MIME type with a default application, there isn't a specification for default application without an associated file to be opened as far as I can tell. Each desktop environment that has a concept of "default terminal emulator" has their own way of configuring it.

Debian has has "update-alternatives" system that allows configuration of "default" applications based on aliases, and it has a package that creates an alias `x-terminal-emulator` that can be used to configure the default terminal emulator.

Here is a reasonable strategy for choosing the command in your program:

- Let the user configure the command. Use this with highest priority if configured.
- Use `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` environment variable, and implement logic for each desktop environment to read their configuration to find out the configured default emulator. Use this as the second highest priority when available.
- Collect a list of commonly used terminal emulators. Put aliases such as `x-terminal-emulator` with higher priority in the list.
- With this list starting with user configuration and ending with your hard-coded list, check each command and see if it's executable and pick the first one that is. In case user has configured the command, and it isn't executable, I recommend an optional error message.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **i3's sensible-terminal** script.

https://github.com/i3/i3/blob/next/i3-sensible-terminal

While it has been made for i3, if you read the source you'll see it's very simple and doesn't rely on it, so feel free to use this within whatever desktop environment you want.

Though if you don't use i3 you may want to remove the last line (which isn't that important as you are unlikely to have no terminal installed at all).

### Explanations

It proceeds by getting, in this order:

- A terminal you may have defined in the non-standard `$TERMINAL` environment variable
- `x-terminal-emulator` which is a similar utility for Debian only
- A list of hardcoded terminals, namely `mate-terminal gnome-terminal terminator xfce4-terminal urxvt rxvt termit Eterm aterm uxterm xterm roxterm termite lxterminal terminology st qterminal lilyterm tilix terminix konsole kitty guake tilda alacritty hyper`